# How to consume Moodle web service functions from c#?

Tags: rest, web, service, moodle

I hava a task to create Moodle courses categories from my c# project, but the following code always return an error response : "Missing required key in single structure: categories"
My code is as follows:

```
        string sitename = "http://localhost/moodle"; 
        string token = "0d31f83da49cc21f8dc599fab4b299f0"; 
        string url = sitename + "/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=" + token + "&wsfunction=core_course_create_categories&moodlewsrestformat=json"; 
        category cat = new category(); 
        List<category> categories = new List<category>(); 
        cat.name = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("2019"); 
        cat.parent = int.Parse(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("2")); 
        cat.idnumber = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("11"); 
        cat.description = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Academic year 2019"); 
        cat.descriptionformat = int.Parse(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1")); 
        cat.theme = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(""); 
        categories.Add(cat); 
        Dictionary<string, List<category>> param = new Dictionary<string, List<category>>(); 
        param.Add("categories", categories.ToList()); 
        string jsonList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param.ToArray(), Formatting.None); 
        var client = new RestClient(url); 
        var request = new RestRequest(); 
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json; 
        request.AddJsonBody(jsonList); 
        request.Method = Method.POST; 
        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

---

### //category class code

```
public class category 
{ 
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public int parent { get; set; } 
    public string idnumber { get; set; } 
    public string description { get; set; } 
    public int descriptionformat { get; set; } 
    public string theme { get; set; } 
    public category() 
    { 
        descriptionformat = 1; 
        theme = ""; 
    } 
}
```

---

Comment: Finally I caught a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
           string sitename = "http://localhost/moodle";
            string token = "0d31f83da49cc21f8dc599fab4b299f0";  
            string url = sitename + "/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=" + token +         "&wsfunction=core_course_create_categories&moodlewsrestformat=json";
            category cat = new category();
            List<category> categories = new List<category>();
            cat.name = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("2019");
            cat.parent = int.Parse(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("0"));
            cat.idnumber = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("11");
            cat.description = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Academic year 2019");
            cat.descriptionformat = int.Parse(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1"));
            cat.theme = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String.Empty);
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("categories[0][name]", "'" + cat.name + "'", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("categories[0][parent]", cat.parent, ParameterType.QueryString);
            request.AddParameter("categories[0][idnumber]", "'" + cat.idnumber + "'", ParameterType.QueryString);
            request.AddParameter("categories[0][description]", "'" + cat.description + "'", ParameterType.QueryString);
            request.AddParameter("categories[0][descriptionformat]", cat.descriptionformat, ParameterType.QueryString);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.Method = Method.POST;
            var response = client.Execute(request);
```